# skip some rows in read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv, readfile

I have a csv file which I read using the following function:

```
csvData <- read.csv(file="pf.csv", colClasses=c(NA, NA,"NULL",NA,"NULL",NA,"NULL","NULL","NULL"))
dimnames(csvData)[[2]]<- c("portfolio", "date", "ticker", "quantity")
```

It reads all lines from that file. But i want to skip some rows from reading. The row should not read if the value of the `ticker`-column is: `ABT` or `ADCT`. Is it possible?

sample of my csv file is as follows:

```
RUS1000,01/29/1999,21st Centy Ins Group,TW.Z,90130N10,72096,1527.534,0.01,21.188
RUS1000,01/29/1999,3com Corp,COMS,88553510,358764,16861.908,0.16,47.000
RUS1000,01/29/1999,3m Co,MMM,88579Y10,401346,31154.482,0.29,77.625
RUS1000,01/29/1999,A D C Telecommunicat,ADCT,00088630,135114,5379.226,0.05,39.813
RUS1000,01/29/1999,Abbott Labs,ABT,00282410,1517621,70474.523,0.66,46.438
RUS1000,02/26/1999,21st Centy Ins Group,TW.Z,90130N10,72096,1378.836,0.01,19.125
RUS1000,02/26/1999,3com Corp,COMS,88553510,358764,11278.644,0.11,31.438
RUS1000,02/26/1999,3m Co,MMM,88579Y10,402146,29783.938,0.29,74.063
```

Comment: Use `readLines` and use regular expressions to filter out undesirable rows.

Comment: Why not read in the whole file and subset later?

Comment: actually the file having 200mb+ and majority of the data contains these values.

Comment: Then you could also preprocess the file with sed or csvkit or something like that and create a smaller csv file to read in. Or, as suggested, explore the sqldf package.

Comment: before using R run: 
`sed '/(,ADCT,|,ABT,)/d' > newfile`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is possible using [sqldf package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html), using `read.csv.sql`

Lets say the contents of `sample.csv` looks like this:

```
id,name,age
1,"a",23
2,"b",24
3,"c",23
```

Now to read only rows where age=23:

```
require(sqldf)

df <- read.csv.sql("sample.csv", "select * from file where age=23")

df
  id name age
1  1  "a"  23
2  3  "c"  23
```

It is possible to select necessary columns:

```
df <- read.csv.sql("sample.csv", "select id, name from file where age=23")
df
  id name
1  1  "a"
2  3  "c"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer? Then it will be more likely to help your answer gain attention.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a simple, self-contained example.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to read all and subset later like suggested in the comment :

```
csvData [!csvData$ticker %in% c('ADCT','ABT'),]
```

**EDIT**

You can use `fread` from `data.table` package for more efficient method to read your file.

```
library(read.table)
fread(file="pf.csv")
```

Comment: Assuming file was too big to read into memory, what would be OP's choices then?

Comment: actually the file having 200mb+ and majority of the data contains these values.So i think it is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

For me the sqldf package's read.csv.sql looked great at first blush.  But when I tried to use it, it failed to deal with "NULL" strings. (Others have found this out as well.)  Unfortunately, it doesn't support all of read.csv features.
So I had to write my own.  I am surprised that there isn't a good package for this.

```
fetchLines=function(inputFile,match,fixed=T,n=100,maxlines=100000){ #inputFile='simple.csv'; match='APPLE';
  message('reading:',inputFile)
  n=min(n,maxlines)
  con  <- base::file(inputFile, open = "r",encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  data=c(readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE))
  while (length(oneLine <- readLines(con, n = n, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
    grab=grep(match,oneLine,value=T,fixed=fixed)
    if(length(grab)>0){
      data=c(data,grab)
      if(length(data)>maxlines){
        warning("bailing out too many");
        return(data);
      }
      cat('.')
    }
  } 
  close(con)
  gc()
  cat("\n")
  data;
}

#To avoid: argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string
fdata=textConnection( fetchLines("datafile.csv",'\\bP58\\b',fixed=F,maxlines = 100000))
df<-read.csv(fdata,header=T,sep=",",na.strings = c('NULL',''),fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM",stringsAsFactors = F)
```

[R textConnection: "argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170633/r-textconnection-argument-object-must-deparse-to-a-single-character-string)

Comment: `read.csv.sql` is based on SQLite facilities, not on `read.table` so one can't really expect that it works exactly the same; however, the `filter=` and `sql=` arguments of `read.csv.sql` can be used for arbitrary preprocessing so depending on what your data looks like arbitrary missing value situations can usually be handled.  For example, `filter = "sed -e s/NULL//g"` would remove all occurrences of the string NULL.  (On Windows it will assume you have Rtools installed and get sed from there.)

Comment: I tried swapping NULLs with empty strings but it wasn't interpreted as NA. Your trick AFAIK would not make it  treat the values as NA.

Comment: If its a numeric field, say, then they will be treated as 0 and you can replace them on the R end.  Or replace NULL with -99, say, and replace them on the R end.

Comment: So a bit of a hack. I'd have to choose a magic numeric and hope it doesn't exist. 0, -1 and -99 are far too common. My function is speedy especially with larger values of n

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in the `readr` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
csvData <- read_csv(file="pf.csv") %>%
 filter(!ticker-column %in% c('ABT','ADCT')
```