# R textConnection: "argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string"

Tags: r

I want to turn a list of strings into a data frame.
however, I get this error:

```
> read.csv(textConnection(c("id,name,count",
                          '6289,aa,16',
                          '6269,bb,8',
                          '6269,cc,8',
                          '6269,dd,8',
                          '6610,ee,4')))
 Error in textConnection(c("id,name,count", "6289,aa,16", "6269,bb,8",  : 
  argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string
Calls: read.csv -> read.table -> textConnection
```

when I remove just one line, it works:

```
> read.csv(textConnection(c("id,name,count",
                          '6289,aa,16',
                          '6269,bb,8',
                          '6269,cc,8',
                          '6610,ee,4')))
   id name count
1 6289   aa    16
2 6269   bb     8
3 6269   cc     8
4 6610   ee     4
```

what is going on?!

Comment: Wierd. If you do `txt <- c( 'id,name,count' ... ); read.csv( textConnection(txt) )` it works just fine. Strange.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with `deparse` and the `width.cutoff` value, which is set to 60. This results in a character string that is more than 1 length.

Comment: Also, just curious: With your stated objective, why are you using `textConnection` instead of the `text` argument to `read.table` and family?

Comment: @AnandaMahto: because I forgot about it; thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ananda has it right that the behavior originates in `deparse`. Under the Details section of the `textConnection()` documentation, it says,

> `object` should be the name of a character vector: however, short expressions will be accepted provided they deparse to less than 60 bytes.

`deparse()` turns expressions into character strings. When an expression deparses to more than 60 bytes, `deparse` tries to split the string into shorter text chunks; i.e., a vector of strings. Try it:

```
deparsed <- deparse(c("this expr","deparses to length=1,","nchar=57 bytes"))
deparsed
[1] "c(\"this expr\", \"deparses to length=1,\", \"nchar=57 bytes\")"
nchar(deparsed)
[1] 57

deparsed <- deparse(c("whereas this longer expression","deparses to length=2,","nchar=c(61,23) bytes"))
deparsed
[1] "c(\"whereas this longer expression\", \"deparses to length=2,\", "
[2] "\"nchar=c(61,23) bytes\")"
nchar(deparsed)
[1] 61 23
```

This is why you're getting the error

```
argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string
```

for your longer expression but not your shorter one.

The solution, as sds and Simon each showed, is to assign your expression to an object and then call textConnection on the object name rather than on the original expression.

```
txt <- c("id,name,count", '6289,aa,16', '6269,bb,8',
         '6269,cc,8', '6269,dd,8', '6610,ee,4')
read.csv(textConnection(txt))
    id name count
1 6289   aa    16
2 6269   bb     8
3 6269   cc     8
4 6269   dd     8
5 6610   ee     4
```

Under the hood, textConnection is now calling `deparse(substitute(txt))` rather than `deparse(substitute(c("id,name,count", ...)))`. Only the shorter expression deparses to a single character string. And that's what `textConnection` needs.

Comment: Much better explanation than what I would have given. +1

Comment: It looks like this was fixed in R 4.1.0: "textConnection() gets an optional name argument" which can be seen [in this commit from August 2021](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/a5353ce04832f4d85d7f26fddc057e7747438c88).

This now works because it uses `deparse1()` from R 4.0: "New function deparse1() produces one string, wrapping deparse(), to be used typically in deparse1(substitute(*)), e.g., to fix [PR#17671](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17671)."