# Convert a string with concatenated indices and values to a vector of values

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
v2      v3
1.000   2:3,3:2,5:2,
2.012   1:5,2:4,6:3,
```

The second column v3, consists of 'index-value' pairs, each pair separated by a `,`.

Within each 'index-value' pair, the number preceeding the `:` is the vector index. The number  after the `:` is the corresponding value. E.g. in the first row, the vector indices are 2, 3, and 5, and the corresponding values are 3, 2, and 2.

Indices not represented in the string should have the value 0 in the resulting vector.

I wish to convert the 'index-value' vector to a vector of values.

Thus, for the two strings above the expected result is:

```
v2     v3
1.000  c(0,3,2,0,2,0)
2.012  c(5,4,0,0,0,3)
```

Comment: Do some reading on regular expressions.

Comment: @LauraS, I don't think this is a trivial question. If you think that a simple regex solution would solve the problem, why don't you post an answer instead of your comment?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thank you so much. It's so kind of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We make use of the `data.table` package just to use its `tstrsplit` function. It removes an intermediate step. Try this:

```
require(data.table)
df$v3<-lapply(
  lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$v3),",",fixed=TRUE),tstrsplit,":"),
   function(x) {res<-numeric(6);res[as.numeric(x[[1]])]<-as.numeric(x[[2]]);res})
#     v2               v3
#1 1.000      0,3,2,0,2,0
#2 2.012      5,4,0,0,0,3
```

- We first split each element of `v3` using the comma (`,`)
- We then split again using the `:` as separator;
- We create a numeric vector of length 6;
- We finally fill the values according the described logic.

Comment: I voted you up here, but I would personally prefer not hard-coding the `numeric(6)` part of the answer.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I agree with you, but the question doesn't give any indication in merit. I wanted to use the `max` index of each element, but in their desired result vectors of length 6 appear. If the OP jumps in and describe better the desired output I'd change accordingly.

Comment: @nicola Actually the merit should be a constant value so your method is OK. Thanks for you reply and I will take a try right now.

Comment: @nicola Sorry I gave forgotten something. There should be a `,` behind each row. So is there should be any change?

Comment: I tested and it works even if there is a comma at the end.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Yes it works and the problem has been solved already. Thanks for you two.

Comment: @nicola @nicola But now I have met another problem. I'd like to convert the V3 to a matrix and take each column of V3 as a vector, and then measure the covariance and correlation between the v2 and each vector. But when do that `cov(as.array(data$V2),as.matrix(data$V3) )`, an error occurs: `Error: is.numeric(y) || is.logical(y) is not TRUE`. Do you have any idea of it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with an approach like that suggested by @nicola, however, for fun, here's an alternative.

Use `read.dcf`, which is used to read "tag:value" type data. To get all the "tags", use the `fields` argument. You've specified this as 1:6 in your comment to @nicola. Also, you need to replace your "," with newline characters (`"\n"`).

We'll store all of this in a string so that `deparse` + `textConnection` [will be able to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170633/r-textconnection-argument-object-must-deparse-to-a-single-character-string). Not necessary for this example, but just in case....

```
str <- gsub(",", "\n", mydf$v3)
x <- read.dcf(textConnection(str), fields = as.character(1:6))
x <- replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
x
#      1   2   3   4   5   6  
# [1,] "0" "3" "2" "0" "2" "0"
# [2,] "5" "4" "0" "0" "0" "3"
```

To get it back in your `data.frame` as a `list` of `numeric` vectors, do this:

```
mydf$v3_l <- lapply(1:nrow(x), function(y) as.numeric(x[y, ]))
```

Here's the resulting `str`:

```
str(mydf)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ v2  : num  1 2.01
 $ v3  : chr  "2:3,3:2,5:2," "1:5,2:4,6:3,"
 $ v3_l:List of 2
  ..$ : num  0 3 2 0 2 0
  ..$ : num  5 4 0 0 0 3
```

Comment: But that approach just returns a list of number instead of a vector. I try to convert them to vector but fail. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using only `base` functions.

First the string is split (`strsplit`) by `:` or `,`. Elements at odd positions correspond to indices, and even positions to values. We pre-allocate a `numeric` vector of `length` of the `max` index.

In the `lapply` loop, we assign the values of the split vector (i.e. the even elements; `x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`) to the pre-alloctad vector `vec`, at the indices (i.e. the odd elements of the splitted vector; `x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`).

```
l <- strsplit(df$v3, "[:|,]")
vec <- numeric(length = max(as.integer(unlist(l)[c(TRUE, FALSE)])))

df$v3 <- lapply(l, function(x){
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  vec[x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]] <- x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
  vec
  })

df
#      v2               v3
# 1 1.000 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0
# 2 2.012 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3
```