# Import excel rows in R based on cell value

Tags: r, import

I want to import only a couple of rows of a large Excel sheet in R (repeatedly, from different sheets, with different rows).
Once imported the whole sheet would look something like:

`data.frame(cat=rep(1:10,each=2),val=rnorm(20,10,1))`
I could of course import and then subset

```
`mydata <- read_excel("file")[var1=="expr",]`
```

but then I would unnecessarily import the whole sheet. Is there any possibility to filter the sheet before importing it?

Comment: You can use the `range` argument of `read_excel` to select the cells you want to import, or a combination of `skip` and `nmax` to select rows

Comment: There is a way you are able to work with csv files instead of excel, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967226/skip-some-rows-in-read-csv-in-r